# pointer segfault problems

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

pointer segfault problems...

I've been doing c++ for some weeks meanwhile but i ran again into that issue.

basically i have these classes given. I cant change them. I start with an instance of `_ns3__importAuftragResponse kout;`

```
class SOAP_CMAC _ns3__importAuftragResponse
{
public:
        ns2__SOAPImportResult *return_;
         ...




class SOAP_CMAC ns2__SOAPImportResult
{
public:
        bool *error;   
        int *numberOfIgnoreds; 
        ....
```

My code needs to check for the numberOfIgnoreds

first approach

```
ns2__SOAPImportResult* imp_result;
imp_result = kout.return_;

int num;
num = *imp_result->numberOfIgnoreds;
```

or i use

```
ns2__SOAPImportResult imp_result;
imp_result = *(kout.return_);
int* num;
*num = *imp_result.numberOfIgnoreds;
```

I mostly get segmentation fault 
I know generally what happens at runtime but cant come up with the correct ode. PLease help.

**EDIT**

made progress thx to your answer, Nawaz , but still need some understanding

```
ns2__SOAPImportResult * imp_ptr = new ns2__SOAPImportResult;
imp_ptr = kout.return_;
int * num = new (int);
// next line segfaults
*num = *imp_ptr->numberOfIgnoreds;
```

what's hard for me to understand is, how or why allocate memory for something that is already "there" as there is the member return_ of the object kout

So is it correct to say I need to allocate memory for the variable I assign it to (which is of same type of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you've not allocated memory for the following members which you're using in the code you've quoted.

```
ns2__SOAPImportResult *return_; //in the class _ns3__importAuftragResponse 


int *numberOfIgnoreds;  //in the class  ns2__SOAPImportResult
```

Other than this I don't see anything where things might go wrong!

Make sure you allocate memory for these members (and all other pointers in your program) **before using them**. You can use `new` to allocate memory. Or alternatively, you can use `malloc()` as well. Whatever you use, use it consistently, and deallocate the memory once you done, using `delete` or `free()` respectively!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [gsoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html). In that case you must use soap_malloc to allocate memory which you return.

For example on the [FAQ](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapfaq.html) page, you will find this example:

```
int ns__itoa(struct soap *soap, int i, char **a)
{ *a = (char*)soap_malloc(soap, 11);
  sprintf(*a, "%d", i);
  return SOAP_OK;
}
```